# Counting points in polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, count

I use QGIS 2.18.16.

I import 1.000.000 data points, from a text document, as a CSV layer.
Then I add a raster of 5 by 5m over those points.

Project, layer and raster are put in the same CRS (Belgian Lambert 72)
After that I count points in polygon.

This works fine.

How do I count point in polygon for up to 5 million data points or more?
When I import more then 1 million I can't count points in polygon no more.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 4):

Do the count five times, and after each count copy the result to a new column in your polygon layer. After the last count, sum up all the columns using the field calc. If you are really lazy like me, build a graphical modell which runs all your steps automatically.

Also, I don't know, whether and/or where to upper boundary for rows in an attribute table is.